# Set dataframe column using values from matching indices in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to set values in `col2` of `DF1` using the value held at the matching index of `col2` in `DF2`:

`DF1`:

```
         col1    col2
index
    0       a
    1       b
    2       c
    3       d
    4       e
    5       f
```

`DF2`:

```
         col1    col2
index
    2       a      x
    3       d      y
    5       f      z
```

`DF3`:

```
         col1    col2
index
    0       a     NaN
    1       b     NaN
    2       c       x
    3       d       y
    4       e     NaN
    5       f       z
```

If I just try and set `DF1['col2'] = DF2['col2']` then `col2` comes out as all `NaN` values in `DF3` - I take it this is because the indices are different. However when I try and use `map()` to do something like:

```
DF1.index.to_series().map(DF2['col2'])
```

then I still get the same `NaN` column, but I thought it would map the values over where the index matches...

What am I not getting?

Comment: you try df1[["col2"]] = df2[["col2"]]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) or [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = df1.join(df2['col2'])
print (df)
      col1 col2
index          
0        a  NaN
1        b  NaN
2        c    x
3        d    y
4        e  NaN
5        f    z
```

Or:

```
df1 = df1.assign(col2=df2['col2']) 
#same like
#df1['col2'] = df2['col2']
print (df1)

      col1 col2
index          
0        a  NaN
1        b  NaN
2        c    x
3        d    y
4        e  NaN
5        f    z
```

If no match and all values are `NaN`s check if indices have same dtype in both `df`:

```
print (df1.index.dtype)
print (df2.index.dtype)
```

If not, then use astype:

```
df1.index = df1.index.astype(int)
df2.index = df2.index.astype(int)
```

---

Bad solution (check index 2):

```
df = df2.combine_first(df1)
print (df)
      col1 col2
index          
0        a  NaN
1        b  NaN
2        a    x
3        d    y
4        e  NaN
5        f    z
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply concat as you are combining based on index

```
df = pd.concat([df1['col1'], df2['col2']],axis = 1)

        col1    col2
index       
0       a   NaN
1       b   NaN
2       c   x
3       d   y
4       e   NaN
5       f   z
```