# Assigning data to slice of a multi-indexed data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multi-indexed data frame that looks like this :

```
iterables = [['House1','House2'],['cats','dogs','birds','hamsters']]
index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables,names=['House','pets'])
df_pets = pandas.DataFrame(index=index,columns=['Number'])
print(df_pets)

                Number
House  pets           
House1 cats        NaN
       dogs        NaN
       birds       NaN
       hamsters    NaN
House2 cats        NaN
       dogs        NaN
       birds       NaN
       hamsters    NaN
```

Now, I'd like to assign data to this data frame using data from a second data frame, given by

```
df_house1 = pandas.DataFrame([1,2],index=['cats','dogs'],columns=['Number'])
print(df_house1)

      Number
cats       1
dogs       2
```

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46896105/set-dataframe-column-using-values-from-matching-indices-in-another-dataframe) it looks like I should be able to use `assign` :

```
idx = pandas.IndexSlice
df1 = df_pets.loc[idx['House1'],:].assign(Number=df_house1['Number'])
print(df1)

          Number
pets            
cats         1.0
dogs         2.0
birds        NaN
hamsters     NaN
```

This successfully matches up the indices, which was my main goal, since I may have missing data.    (Why it changes the data type is a mystery).

My question is, how do I update the original DataFrame `df_pets`? Here is what I get when I make the obvious assignment.

```
df_pets.loc[idx['House1'],:] = df1
print(df_pets)

                Number
House  pets           
House1 cats        NaN
       dogs        NaN
       birds       NaN
       hamsters    NaN
House2 cats        NaN
       dogs        NaN
       birds       NaN
       hamsters    NaN
```

I read in the post referenced above that there might be a type mismatch.  But I checked types for both the original data frame and the one containing the data I want to use for assignment :

```
print(df1.index.dtype)
print(df_pets.index.dtype)

object
object
```

What am I missing?  Or, maybe there is another way to assign data to a slice of a multi-indexed dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try assign it through ndarray

```
df_pets.loc[idx['House1', df_house1.index.tolist()],:] = df_house1.values

Out[296]:
                Number
House  pets
House1 cats          1
       dogs          2
       birds       NaN
       hamsters    NaN
House2 cats        NaN
       dogs        NaN
       birds       NaN
       hamsters    NaN
```

Comment: Can I assume that  `to_list` and `values` will have consistent ordering?

Comment: `tolist` keeps the order of index, so its order will be the same as ndarray returns by `values`.