# Nested loop - alternative solution - Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, if-statement, nested

I have started learning python, and I wanted to ask if there is an alternative faster solution to the below nested loop:

```
for y in range(total_rows2):
    for x in range(total_rows1):
        if df2.iloc[y,0]==df1.iloc[x,0]:
            df1.iloc[x,1]=df1.iloc[x,1]+df2.iloc[y,17]
```

Basically, I have found the number of rows (total_rows1 and total_rows2) of two dataframes (df1 and df2). The first column of both dataframes (index=0) correspond to some IDs.

If the IDs of the two dataframes match, then I want to add the value of column 18 of df2(index 17, column name='Profit') to the second column of df1 (index=1, column name='Profit'). An id may appear twice in df2 but I will appear the sum in df1 (please see below for id 0108). So the 'Profit' column of df1 will be the sum of Profit per ID.

df2:

| --- | ID | Profit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0104 | 0 |
| 1 | 0106 | 0 |
| 2 | 0107 | 0 |
| 3 | 0108 | 0 |

df1:

| --- | ID | Loss | Profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0104 | 100 | 230 |
| 1 | 0106 | 200 | 150 |
| 2 | 0108 | 150 | 120 |
| 3 | 0107 | 120 | 230 |
| 4 | 0109 | 100 | 400 |
| 5 | 0108 | 150 | 400 |

So I want df2 to look as followed:

| --- | ID | Profit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0104 | 230 |
| 1 | 0106 | 150 |
| 2 | 0107 | 230 |
| 3 | 0108 | 520 |

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46896105/set-dataframe-column-using-values-from-matching-indices-in-another-dataframe?

Comment: `df1.assign(col2=df2['col17']) `

Comment: Are df1 and df2 in the same shape? (same number of rows and column) or not at all? Have you got a small example to help us to reproduce the code and make understand faster what's your goal?

Comment: Hi, no the dataframes have different shapes, I have added some more details on my initial post! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think just merging the two dfs on that first column and then doing the addition would be fine.

frames:

```
>>> df1
  ID  B  C  D
0  e  3  8  1
1  d  5  1  1
2  g  6  5  1
3  e  8  8  7
4  j  9  3  6
5  i  4  0  5
6  g  0  4  1
7  a  3  7  2
8  e  0  6  9
9  b  2  9  6
>>> df2
  ID  col_17
0  j       9
1  c       3
2  d       6
3  g       4
4  h       4
5  g       5
6  e       1
7  d       8
8  b       0
9  i       6
```

Merge:

```
>>> df3 = df1.merge(df2,how='left',on='ID')
>>> df3
   ID  B  C  D  col_17
0   e  3  8  1     1.0
1   d  5  1  1     6.0
2   d  5  1  1     8.0
3   g  6  5  1     4.0
4   g  6  5  1     5.0
5   e  8  8  7     1.0
6   j  9  3  6     9.0
7   i  4  0  5     6.0
8   g  0  4  1     4.0
9   g  0  4  1     5.0
10  a  3  7  2     NaN
11  e  0  6  9     1.0
12  b  2  9  6     0.0
```

Add:

```
>>> df3['B']=np.where(df3['col_17'].notna(),df3['B']+df3['col_17'],df3['B'])
>>> df3
   ID     B  C  D  col_17
0   e   4.0  8  1     1.0
1   d  11.0  1  1     6.0
2   d  13.0  1  1     8.0
3   g  10.0  5  1     4.0
4   g  11.0  5  1     5.0
5   e   9.0  8  7     1.0
6   j  18.0  3  6     9.0
7   i  10.0  0  5     6.0
8   g   4.0  4  1     4.0
9   g   5.0  4  1     5.0
10  a   3.0  7  2     NaN
11  e   1.0  6  9     1.0
12  b   2.0  9  6     0.0
```